# Sharing session values between MVC and PHP

Tags: session

I need to pass the stored current session user id value from ASP.NET(MVC) to another website in another platform.

Comment: Check out **localStorage** in the browser.

Comment: And what have you tried? *please edit this in the question*

Comment: I need to transfer the current session user id from mvc site to php site. So i used cookies and it is working fine. but transferring with cookies is not secure, so i need to use session for sharing userid among website. how to do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i found the answer.... Use $_REMOTESERVER['Userid'] for getting the current session userid (without using cookies stored on the client browser) from mvc to php